# How to access to an interface device in C?

Tags: c, io

I have a smart card reader connected to my Linux machine seen as *Generic Smart Card Reader Interface [Smart Card Reader Interface] (20070818000000000) 00 00* (I saw this through the `pcsc_scan` command).
I'd like to write a program in C that would allow me to manipulate raw data from the card, but I don't know how to access to this device, would you mind to help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: _Write a program in c_  then _but I don't know how to access to this device_.  It seems the problem has nothing to do with writing something in C, and everything to do with accessing the device. Should the C tag be removed?

Comment: The card reader will likely show up in `/dev/` so find out what file it is there and then google about how to read from "device files"

Comment: A quick web search with "how to use pcsc" revealed several usable pages. Did you read any of them?

Comment: Thanks to all of you. Unfortunately there's no device in /dev linked to my card reader, would've been too easy...
I read something abut pcsc but it seems monopolized by MIFARE card tutorials and nothing very useful anyways. Gonna looking for something good.

Answer (score 0):

these are available commands to list devices in linux

```
ls: List files in the file system.
lsblk: List block devices (for example, the drives).
lspci: List PCI devices.
lsusb: List USB devices.
lsdev: List all devices.
```

then use [this page](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-use-linux-to-find-the-names-of-the-devices-on-your-computer-4078068)

to 'mount' that device as part of your file system read:

```
man mount
```

Once the above details are handled, then the 'C' program can use `fopen()` or `open()` to access the device,

then use: `fread()` and `fwrite()` or `read()` and `write()` to communicate with the device

You might also want to read [obtain manufacture name](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58117/determine-xinput-device-manufacturer-and-model)  to use for determining which device in `/dev` is the one your interested in.

[to abtain device manufacture and model](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58117/determine-xinput-device-manufacturer-and-model)  suggest using:

```
lsusb -v | grep -e idProduct -e idVendor
```